# Xcode : Apple Mach-O linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode

I made the app in Xcode 4.6 and tested in device. The app is made for both iPhone and iPad. When I try to archive it to make .ipa file, I get this error :

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/admin/Desktop/appName/appName/libzbar.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to set the architecture for this in Build Settings? Or is there some different issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libzbar.a library needs to be built for armv7s architecture. If you cannot do that (because you don't have source code for this library) than you should remove armv7s from valid architectures. 
You can change valid architectures by following steps:

- select project name from the Project Navigator
- select project target
- open Build Settings tab
- change valid architectures field

Comment: change to what? arm 6 or lower versions? will you please mention the exact change

Comment: You can change it to armv6 and armv6s

Comment: not working.. still get the same error message if i add armv6, armv5 in its architecture.

Comment: I can only think of one more thing.
In the same tab as for valid architectures, set the "Build Active Architecture Only" setting to YES

Comment: I'm relieved..that was the last thing I had :)